# Natural Environment Illumination in Augmented Reality

Tags: global-illumination, mobile

I've basically 0-knowledge about augmented reality. For academic purposes I've to study this paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8007317/?reload=true

I'm struggling trying to understand some unclear concepts to me:

- what's environment mapping in this context?
- what's basically "distance impostor tracing"?

I've several doubts about the rest of the paper too, maybe someone may have some simple references to make me understand what's the pipeline they present does.

Answer (score 0):

This probably should go as a comment; however I don't have enough reputations to do so.

I don't have access to the paper, and probably most of the people here don't either.

Did you check about the standard concepts in Computer Graphics of [environment mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_mapping) and [impostor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics))? Do they make sense in this context or did the authors invent something new for their framework?

I would say those are common techniques to reduce the scene complexity (which improves the performance of AR/VR systems), while trying to provide some level of reality.

Comment: The distance impostor concept is somehow related to the classical "impostor" definition, but I do not get how. The concept should be more clear in this paper http://sirkan.iit.bme.hu/~szirmay/ibl3.pdf